# javascript drag events not being registered

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, drag-and-drop

I am trying to call a handler function whenever a DOM object is dragged and dropped over an html5 canvas, but for some reason, the event is not being triggered.

According to Mozilla Developer Network, the event I am looking for is `drop` or `dragend`.  This is directly from this reference. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

`dragend` - A drag operation is being ended(by releasing a mouse button or hitting the escape key)
`drop` - An element is dropped on a valid target

Here's a JS fiddle of a simple test case I set up. I set logger functions so that I could test which events were being triggered. An orange canvas is present with a button and an image of a black dot. The black dot and button are both draggable elements. When they are dragged and dropped on the canvas the `drop` or `dragend` events are not triggered. Why not?

The only drag event being triggered is `dragover`!

https://jsfiddle.net/ex080/wktm3nkd/3/

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <button v-bind:draggable="true">drag_me </button>
  <img src="http://www.emoji.co.uk/files/microsoft-emojis/symbols-windows10/10296-medium-black-circle.png" width=10 height=10 v-bind:draggable="true"/>
  <canvas
    id=canvas
    width="200"
    height="200"
    @mousedown="mousedown"
    @mouseup="mouseup"
    @mousemove="mousemove"
    @dragend="dragend"
    @drop="drop"
    @drag="drag"
    @dragover="dragover"
  ></canvas>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  methods:{
    mousedown(event){
    console.log('mousedown')
    },
    mouseup(event){
    console.log('mouseup')
    },
    mousemove(event){
    console.log('mousemove')
    },
    dragend(event){
      console.log("mouseend")
    },
    drop(event){
      console.log("drop")
    },
    drag(event){
      console.log("drag")
    },
    dragover(event){
      console.log("dragover")
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `event.preventDefault();` into your `dragover` method.

From: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp:

> The ondragover event specifies where the dragged data can be dropped.
>
> By default, data/elements cannot be dropped in other elements. To allow a drop, we must prevent the default handling of the element.
>
> This is done by calling the event.preventDefault() method for the ondragover event: